# Apple Sign In fails without error after changing certificates

Tags: swift, xcode, sign-in-with-apple

Sign in with Apple was implemented and working well in a Swift project. I had to revoke the distribution certificates and profiles, and build with new ones, (the code wasn't touched), this caused the Apple Sign In to stop working. It shows no error, just a message "Sign Up not Completed" appears on the screen on the bottom of the Apple Sign In dialog.

I have tried clean, rebuild, clear DerivedData, remove & add again the capability of 'Sign In with Apple', nothing has worked. What to do?

Comment: Have you tried removing your app from "Apps using Apple ID" in your phone settings?

Comment: the app doesnt appear in that list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anybody has this problem, here's the solution.

Go to developer.apple.com, Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles -> Identifiers.

Find your App ID and from its capabilities, remove "Sign in with apple" and click save. Then add it again and save. This resets the provisioning profiles for the app ID.
P.S. Removing and adding the capability from XCode setting, won't work. You need to do it from the developer account site.